# cast pointers address offset varies

Tags: c, endianness

I've wrote a piece of code to determine my system's byte ordering. But the output confuses me.

```
...
    int a = 0x12345678;
    uint8_t c0, c1, c2, c3;

    c0 = *( (uint8_t *)&a   );
    c1 = *( (uint8_t *)&a+1 );
    c2 = *( (uint8_t *)&a+2 );
    c3 = *( (uint8_t *)&a+3 );

    /* Print addresses of all the variables. */
...
```

Output:

```
&a : 0xbf9b23f8  
&c0: 0xbf9b23fc   // &c0 - &a = 4, Why &a != &c0 ? 
&c1: 0xbf9b23fd    
&c2: 0xbf9b23fe    
&c3: 0xbf9b23ff
```

If I comment some statements, the offset will vary.

```
...
    int a = 0x12345678;
    uint8_t c0;

    c0 = *( (uint8_t *)&a   );
...
```

Output:

```
&a : 0xbf893788
&c0: 0xbf89378f    // &c0 - &a = 7 ??
```

Comment: Scrape all the code away except the variable declarations. Now ask your question again. "Why &a != &c0" How about because *they're different variables* ? You should be looking at the *values* of `c0..c3`, not the addresses.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes. I've printed the values of them all and the result was correct.

Comment: How can two different variables be in the same place in memory..?

Comment: @Wisatbff **Why &a != &c0 ?** I dont understand why you are expecting the address of a to be equal to c0. You declared two variables which obviously takes different memory address.

Comment: @Wisatbff Perhaps you want to try like this `uint8_t *c0, *c1, *c2, *c3;
    c0 = (uint8_t *)&a;
    c1 = (uint8_t *)&a+1;
    c2 = (uint8_t *)&a+2;
    c3 = (uint8_t *)&a+3; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest a simpler approach?

```
int a=0x01234567;
unsigned char *c;
c = (unsigned char*)(&a);
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
  printf("byte %d = %02x\n", i, c[i]);
}
```

But to answer your underlying question - when you set the variable `c0` equal to the value of the first byte of `a`, that doesn't mean they share the same address...

Always keep your code as simple as possible, but no simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified few things in your source code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>  // for uint8_t
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a = 0x12345678;
    uint8_t *c0, *c1, *c2, *c3; // Changed to pointers

    c0 = (uint8_t *)&a;      //address is stored
    c1 = (uint8_t *)&a+1;
    c2 = (uint8_t *)&a+2;
    c3 = (uint8_t *)&a+3;

    printf("&a : %p\n", (void *)&a );
    printf("&c0: %p\n", (void *)c0);
    printf("&c1: %p\n", (void *)c1);
    printf("&c2: %p\n", (void *)c2);
    printf("&c3: %p\n", (void *)c3);
    exit(0);
}
```

Output:

```
&a : 0022FF34
&c0: 0022FF34
&c1: 0022FF35
&c2: 0022FF36
&c3: 0022FF37
```

Comment: Except you are no longer printing &c0 and so on, you are printing the contents of the pointer variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the *addresses of the variables*. Why do you expect an address to change? It contains data which was copied from the partial address of another variable, but there is no relation between the addresses of c0 to c3 and the algorithm you are using them for (printing the address of `a` byte-per-byte).

> &c0 - &a = 4, Why &a != &c0 ?

Because they are different variables.

> If I comment some statements, the offset will vary.

The compiler is free to allocate the objects on the stack as it pleases. You cannot know how or where a variable will be allocated on the stack in advance. The compiler will most likely attempt to align your variables properly in the stack frame.